# Borderlands handsome collection loyalty rewards

Tags: ps3, ps4, borderlands

I bought the borderlands handsome collection for ps4 a while back and set up my shift account. I just recently found out I could get shift keys and extra guns if I previously played on ps3 and downloaded a previous save. I'm wondering if I could use the ps3 I have, go buy borderlands 2 or pre-sequel from a store, play it upload a save and download it on the ps4 and still get the keys and content.

Comment: Seems legit. Shift can be buggy though, so I'd wait to hear from a tester or authoritative source before buying

Comment: I don't see why not.  Cross-save between the original, BL2 and BL:TPS works okay on one system (or has for me anyway) so as long as you're using the same email address for your shift account on both systems, then it should work.